# Regex to match string of unique characters

Tags: java, regex, unique

Here is my regular expression:

```
((GO)( [A-Z])+)
```

I want every letter to appear at most once, unfortunately it isn't working properly, because this input:

```
GO A B C C
```

return true, but should return false.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I decide to use @anubhava solution. I need space between letters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(GO(?: ([A-Z])(?!.*\2))+)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eR9kQ6/1)

Answer (score 5):

Your regex is:

```
GO(?:([A-Z])(?!.*\1))+$
```

- Matches the literal `GO`, followed by:
- Any character A-Z, from zero to infinite times
- asserting, for each character encountered, that the same character does not match any (`.`) subsequent character before the next line break (`$`).

The key to that last step, which is all you were missing, is the [zero-length negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?!.*\1)`

Comment: Did you test your regex?  (there is one minor mistake, you can find what it is in [anubhavas` answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26433983/1393766)).

Comment: Nope @Pshemo, you caught me - I was winging that one. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex:

```
^GO (?:([A-Z])(?!.*\1)\s*)*$
```

It will match anything that:

- starts with `GO<space>`
- contains only letters (`[A-Z]`) that:

  - may be separated by any sequence of **blank** characters, but:
  - may not have ever been seen before.

See it [working on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vX6xI4/1)!

---

Sample matching cases:

```
GO A B C
GO ABC
GO A B C G O
```

Sample non-matching cases:

```
A B C
GO A A A
```

Comment: I am not sure if `GO ABC` should be among matching cases (it is just a hunch based on OP regex and example).

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure either. However I usually develop my solutions based on stated requirements more than on the only bit of sample data supplied, and the requirement only says that `I want every letter to appear at most once` ;)